# Aligning animation frame assets with different sizes

Tags: libgdx, animation, sprites, assets, spritebatch

I have code that changes texture in each frame depending on the player's state - walking, idle.

My problem is that the idle texture (from separate png) has a slightly different size, and due to that it appears not in line with rest of the animations, seemingly being in a slightly different position when returning to idle.

How can I position the frames based on the center of texture instead of the bottom left?

```
batch.draw(determineTexture(), position.x, position.y,
            currentFrame.getRegionWidth()/2f, currentFrame.getRegionHeight()/2f,
            currentFrame.getRegionWidth(), currentFrame.getRegionHeight(),1f,1f, rotation,false);

TextureRegion determineTexture(){
        if(playerState == State.idle)
            currentFrame = idleAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
        else if (playerState == State.walkingUP || playerState == State.walkingDOWN || playerState == State.walkingRIGHT || playerState == State.walkingLEFT )
            currentFrame = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
        return currentFrame;
}
```

One png has a height of 57 - idle, while 6 columns and one row of walking frames have a height of 87 pixels.

Comment: Why don't you make them the same size?

Comment: See [some past Q&A about a similar issue](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/172038/39518).

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Tried it just resizing png with this https://www.ps2pdf.com/resize-png but now image is blurry and visibly bigger by ~ 25 % from other frames of animation. Its just that walking animation has arms spread wider and its bigger in resolution size thanks to that.

Comment: @DMGregory a bit simillar at first glance thanks, but not really useful :(. Shame i really struggle right now because that free asset pack looks cool and i wonder if thats me doing something wrong or i should look for new asset pack because you cant have two different heights.

Comment: What force in the universe prevents you from having two different heights? Just offset your draw position accordingly, using a defined hotpoint/pivot you've defined each frame. This is addition and subtraction, not the halting problem.

Comment: @DMGregory So substract difference of 87-57 from position.y and same for position.x ? I hate hardcoding those things tho. maybe i could calculate that automatically based on image when loading assets in separate class? I dont want to use silver tape solutions as i want code to be highly modifyable and universal for future games

Comment: That corresponds to one choice of hotpoint. Whether it's the correct choice for your sprites is something only you can determine, since I cannot see your sprites.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED ! I have modified the code as follows: instead of just position.x and position.y as arguments in SpriteBatch.draw() i modified those values as follows after some trial and error

```
position.x - currentFrame.getRegionWidth()/2f 
position.y - currentFrame.getRegionHeight()/2f
```

So batch draw call looks now like this:

```
 batch.draw(determineTexture(), position.x - currentFrame.getRegionWidth()/2f, position.y - currentFrame.getRegionHeight()/2f,
            currentFrame.getRegionWidth()/2f, currentFrame.getRegionHeight()/2f,
            currentFrame.getRegionWidth(), currentFrame.getRegionHeight(),1f,1f, rotation,false);
```

That makes it centered every time i think Maybe i should mark it as beginner question next time but it felt satysfying to solve after some hints from @DMGregory thanks

Comment: This answer would be better if it showed the code change in context and described how/why making this change solves your problem.

Comment: @DMGregory I am still figuring out why it works